# Capture all WordPress events via plugin

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I am trying to create a plugin in WordPress to show every notifications in dashboard at bottom WordPress Multi-Site.

Suppose a user is editing a post or installing a plugin, then it will be shown to every user login to dashboard of that site. These notification will be real time notifications.

How to capture plugin installed, activated .., I have searched about it and google shows `register_activation_hook`.

Another case Post edit by user:

Suppose a User A is editing a post and User B see a message that User A is editing this post, this message show only when someone try to edit the locked post, below is the screenshot of message.

```
function general_admin_notice(){
    global $pagenow;
    $allpost = get_posts(); 

    if ( $pagenow == 'post.php' && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' ) {        
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $current_user = get_current_user_id();
            $user_editing = wp_check_post_lock($post_id); 
            if($user_editing)
            {
                $user = get_userdata($user_editing);

                echo $user->data->display_name . " is editing post";                

            }

    }

}
```

[image: screenshot]

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure there's a plugin that does something similar already but I can't recall its name at the moment. Anyways, Stack Overflow is a website about programming. Asking for suggestions is considered as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Give it an honest shot at coding your own solution and if you get stuck at some point show us what you got and we'll gladly help you out.

Comment: I have tried to capture a event if plugin is installed then notification message will show to all login users, but i am failed to capture plugin install event, can you help me with that?